# Prevent data loss when refreshed/lost connection on Angular

Tags: angular, local-storage, session-storage

In Angular when you refresh the page then you basically lose your whole app's progress & variables. What is the *best* way to prevent this loss?

I know of session/local storage, which is what we have been using most of the time. But I can't think that this is a good thing to use because:

- Your data is extremely visible to the front end. (I don't store passwords or anything there, but this is still bad. ID's, GUIDS, other user's/table's data is very visible)
- Your data can also build up on the system, which could make the
  user's machine/experience slow.

In general I just have a gut feel that the use of local/session storage is something you should try and avoid as far as possible. So I was just wondering if anyone has any other solutions.

Comment: If you refresh then you have your backend ( server side ) to provide the data. If you lose the connection then you're forced to use client side storage ( localStorage, IndexedDB, SQLite etc.. ). There is no other way to work if there is no conection to the server. Obviously sensitive data should never be stored in client side

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 major methods to store data on the client side

1) **As URL params**

You could store all the state required to render the page the way it should within the route. You are limited by the route manipulation logic and the size. Also, you can only store string and will have to serialize other data manually

2) **In IndexedDB**

Better than localStorage, actions are asynchronous. Harder to manipulate directly, but can use libraries that provide interface similar to localStorage

3) **localStorage/sessionStorage**

Simple key-value store. Easy to use and update. Synchronous and blocking API. Maximum size may depend on the browser. Can be used to store data. Consider encryption if storing sensitive data(though not recommended to begin with)

4) **cookies**

Only strings, limited size, will have to serialize data

All libraries you use would be essentially playing over these 4 available base structures. `Best` is a relative term. Unless you are syncing the data periodically with the server (like auto-save, say) and rehydrating UI on refresh with the server data, you have to choose based on the strategy and data